# User-defined function that counts the amount of products from each category that a person bought

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

Cart Table columns:

```
ID
ProductID
MemberID
CategoryID
```

I've already created a function that returns how many products a member has in his/her cart, but now I want to `CREATE FUNCTION` that returns those products sorted by category. So if I were to activate the function and input the ID, it'd return to me two columns: one called "Category" and the other called "Amount of products" which is the amount of products that a member bought which correspond to that particular category.

Anyone have a clue how to do this? I fiddled around with multiple variables, but I don't quite think that's it.

Sample data example

```
ID    ProductID    MemberID    CategoryID
1         3           2             2
2         2           2             2
3         4           2             1
```

So the end result should be, for Member ID (2)

```
Category      Amount of Products
2             2
1             1
```

Comment: Please do show us your attempt and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  This sounds like a simple `GROUP BY` query with a filter.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the reply! I deleted my attempt after being frustrated with it through multiple tries. It consisted of multiple Category declarations for each specific category (Category1, Category2 etc) and ultimately lead to me just being too confused and getting lost in my code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edited with some sample data and desired results! Hope this makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select categoryid,count(*) from carttable group by categoryid
```